# Excel 2007 Database Date Formatting

Tags: excel

I have a list of 568 dates in a excel table.

I read the first few dates as mm/dd/yyyy as follows,

```
1/2/2009 (Jan 2)
1/2/2009 (Jan 2)
1/16/2009 (Jan 16)
2/1/2009 (Feb 6)
```

When I select format cells the computer converts to dd/mm/yyyy as follows as rewrites as,

```
2/1/2009 (Feb 1)    << Switches date and month.
2/1/2009 (Feb 1)    << Switches date and month.
1/16/2009 (Jan 16)  << Leaves in place because it cant convert 16 to a month
1/2/2009 (Jan 2)    << Switches date and month.
```

I tried to copy and past special-values into pre-formated cells but the problem persists. The cells cant be formatted prior to this action because it converts all the value.
Also tried SQL formatting update which did not work.

Note: This is a spread sheet coming from a mac computer.

Note: If I type the date into the field it gives me the correct format. But if I cut and past the date, it gives me the old cell format that I cant seem to change, even if I past special value.

I plan to retype the dates manually but I rather not because this list is already perfect and I think this excel program should be able to fix this. Any help would be great.

I need the program to think of these dates as they are already listed... as mm/dd/yyyy with no Strings attached!

Comment: What is your locale in the control panel under Regional and Language Options? The order or the date is set there.

Comment: There is other software depending on my computers date formatting so I prefer not to change it. Need to know how to set these dates as MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

Format 568 dates to your custom format of mm/dd/yyyy, next copy the cells, then choose paste special->values to paste them into the pre-formatted cells.

Comment: That did not work. Even if I format the cells, before, after or whatever. It will convert all the dates it can to DD/MM/YYYY (system format) and leave the other dates as MM/DD/YYYY if the MM column is above 12.

Comment: CORRECTION.. It will leave the other dates as MM/DD/YYYY but only if the DD column is 12 or less.

Comment: @chris I tested before I posted. Perhaps I did not explain properly? The idea is to format a range of cells and paste-special the date values into that range.

Comment: I have reposed the problem up top. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I see I have misunderstood you. How about a formula: `=DATE(YEAR(A1), DAY(A1), MONTH(A1))` . Things get a little complicated when you have different format to the system format.

Comment: SUCCESS kinda... I wrote a VB program that puts each date in a string then reverses the "day" and the "month" values then throughs it back into the table. It worked. This wasn't perfect but it worked! Thanks for trying to assist.